# MongoDB get latest documents inside array object

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, database-schema

My Schema looks something like this:

```
{
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  names: [
    {
      value: { type: String, required: true },
      changed_at: { type: Date, index: true, default: Date.now },
    },
  ],
}
```

With aggregation I want find 3 documents of my collection with the most recent date of **names -> changed_at**.

I tried something like this:

```
[
    { $unwind: '$names' },
    { $sort: { 'names.changed_at': -1 } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        names: { $push: { value: '$names.value', changed_at: '$names.changed_at' } },
        id: { $first: '$id' },
      },
    },
    { $limit: 3 },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'users',
        localField: 'id',
        foreignField: 'id',
        as: 'user',
      },
    },
    { $unwind: '$user' },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        old_name: { $first: '$names' },
        user: { avatar_url: 1, current_tag: 1 },
      },
    },
  ]
```

But this does not return the 3 most recent updated documents. How can I make up my query?

Comment: until    `{ $limit: 3 }` all was ok?  check the stages one by one, to see where the problem happens, you sort by names.changed, and then you group by other field, so sort order is only kept inside the group (groups are not sorted)

Comment: The query works, but it does not correctly return the latest documents. I want all documents of the collection sorted by names.changed_at and only return 3

Answer (score 0):

Query

- create a multikey index on `"names.changed_at"`
- sort on the array(`names.changed_at`) by -1, its like sorting based on the max member of the array

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cUiuzKuTbCA)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "names.changed_at": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 3
  }
])
```

---

Query2
(alternative solution, like do manually what the above does auto)

- for each document set the max-date, as extra field
  (its the document representative, shows the last date in all the
  names array)
- sort by it
- limit 3

=> you have the 3 documents that have the latests dates
(query doesn't return 3 latest global dates, those could be all in 1 document)

I used numbers for simplicity, dates are the same.

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6m_NePOVQ8g)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "max-date": {
        "$max": "$names.changed_at"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "max-date": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 3
  }
])
```

If you can send some feedback on perfomance, if you have big collection. Comparing those 2 ways.

Second query can be super fast if you add to your schema, the field "max-date"(with index on it) and update it when you add dates on `names` (this will make very small index also, and will be fast for sure)

Comment: This works :) But what about time efficiency?

Comment: i added a better way, if you can test them, if you have a multikey index on  `names.changed_at` i think will be fast. If its not fast you can keep the second way and add a field `max-date` and create an index on it ,  if you have alot of data, and you test those 2 solutions, send some feedback, on perfomance if you can.